# Extract number between underscore in text

Tags: r, rstudio, special-characters, stringr

I have files with names like

- Hughson.George_54_4
- Ifran.Dean_51_3
- Houston.Amanda_49_6

I'd like to create a data frame where each row is information extracted from a file name in the form of Author, Volume, Issue.

I'm able to extract the name and volume, but can't seem to get the issue number. Using "stringr" package, I've done the following, which gives me `_4` instead of just `4`.

```
[^a-z](?:[^_]+_){0}([^_ ]+$)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for:

```
read.table(text = string, sep ='_', col.names = c('Author', 'Volume', 'Issue'))

          Author Volume Issue
1 Hughson.George     54     4
2     Ifran.Dean     51     3
3 Houston.Amanda     49     6
```

where

```
string <- c("Hughson.George_54_4", "Ifran.Dean_51_3", "Houston.Amanda_49_6")
```

edit:
 You are looking for:

```
 read.table(text = string, sep ='_', fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like this. Its just that in the start I have to build a Corpus and from that point need to make it a data frame.

Comment: Yes, I have already created one. `my.text.location <- "C:/Users/mrina/OneDrive/Documents/Text/Chap 4/EnglishAbstract/"
apapers <- VCorpus(DirSource(my.text.location))
papertitles <- unlist(meta(apapers,tag='id'))
papertitles`

Comment: then in place of string put papertiles and run the code

Comment: Tried that gave me an error. `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 703 did not have 3 elements`

Comment: This does the job too, awesome!

Comment: Also if I want to add another column 'Id' that is just a numeric one like 1,2,3,4 before 'Authors', how can i achieve that?

Comment: just save the dataframe first, is `a = read.table(…)` then do `cbind(id = 1:nrow(a),a)`

Comment: Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is the last digit, we can just use `base R` methods to extract it

```
as.numeric(substring(str1, nchar(str1)))
```

Or with `sub`

```
as.numeric(sub(".*_", "", str1))
#[1] 4 3 6
```

---

If we need to split it to individual columns, one option is `separate` from `tidyverse` which will `split` the column into indvidual columns based on the delimiter (`_`) and also ensure that the type of column is `convert`ed

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(col1 = str1) %>%
    separate(col1, into = c("Author", "Volume", "Issue"), sep = "_", convert = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Author         Volume Issue
#  <chr>          <chr>  <chr>
#1 Hughson.George 54     4    
#2 Ifran.Dean     51     3    
#3 Houston.Amanda 49     6
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Hughson.George_54_4", "Ifran.Dean_51_3", "Houston.Amanda_49_6")
```

Comment: Hello, well all these files are in a folder and im reading them, so like there are around 1,303 files.                                                                                          `apapers <- VCorpus(DirSource(my.text.location))
class(apapers)
summary(apapers)
papertitles <- unlist(meta(apapers,tag='id'))
papertitles`                                                                                                                     `issues <- str_extract_all(papertitles, "[^a-z](?:[^_]+_){0}([^_ ]+$)")` So its basically referring to "papertitles"

Comment: @darkpunk No problem.  You can get the names of all the files with `list.files` i.e. `tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(lis.files()))`

Comment: Oh reading isnt an issue, there is a certain way our professsor told us and im sticking to that, but will give this method a shot. Its just this small issue which I cant seem to figure out why the extra _

Comment: Will try to work with this and check. Appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, `separate` did the job too. So many ways for like this one thing. Amazing help!

Answer (score 0):

The `[^a-z]` part of your regex is matching the `_` preceding the last digit. Just use something to match only the digits at the end:

```
x1 <- c("Hughson.George_54_4", "Ifran.Dean_51_3", "Houston.Amanda_49_6")

str_extract(x1,"([^_]+$)")
[1] "4" "3" "6"

str_extract(x1,"\\d+$")
[1] "4" "3" "6"
```

You overall aim seems like a job for `strsplit` though:

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind",strsplit(sub("\\."," ",x1),"_")))
              X1 X2 X3
1 Hughson George 54  4
2     Ifran Dean 51  3
3 Houston Amanda 49  6
```

Comment: This seems to have worked with as a solution. Thanks. Yes the overall job is just to create data frame but my professor wanted us to create these objects like 'Author', 'Volume' etc and then use them to create a  data frame.